# Footer under fixed divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently having difficulty getting the footer of my website to work properly. I think it's because of my fixed positioned header and container divs but I need them to be fixed to stay on top when scrolling. I'm not sure how to take this into account for the footer to appear at the bottom when the container div is empty.

HTML:-

```
 <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerContent">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#container').css('marginTop', $('#header').outerHeight(true) + $('#navbar').outerHeight(true) );
            });
        </script>  
                <div id="navbar">
                    <div id ="navbarContent">  

                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        <div id="footerContent">
        </div>
        </div>   
 </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:-

```
#container{
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}


#navbar{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#4e8885;
    position:fixed;
    top:120px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#8bbcba;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    min-height:20px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#8bbcba;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example page where this is not working online?

Comment: do you mean you want the footer to stay fixed like a toolbar along the bottom of the screen or do you mean you want it to pull up to be below any content?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone No, I'd just like the footer to be in line with the bottom of the page so you don't have to scroll to get to it if the container has no content for example

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Hi Pete, appreciate your answer but the container needs to know when to start otherwise the container won't begin 160 pixels down the page. (This is due to the fixed positions of the header and navbar).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27334/discussion-between-user1060187-and-peter-featherstone)

Answer (score 0):

In your example using fixed heights, it's not necessary to dynamically calculate the margins. You should just be able to set the margins of `container` to match the totals of your headers and footer for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` respectively. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Jdrr/

If you need to dynamically calculate it, you should be able to do it based on this arrangement.

Comment: if you get rid of all of the content in the container, the footer still remains below the bottom of the screen..

Comment: @user1060187 That's only because I put a `min-height` on the `container` element. If you want it to scale down to 0 height, simply remove the `min-height: 300px;` and it should work properly.

Comment: The footer would then just appear directly after the navbar then wouldn't it?

Comment: @user1060187 Yes. I guess I'm not sure what you're asking for: the footer is always at the bottom of the content, regardless of the content's height. Is that not the desired behavior?

Comment: Essentially because of the fixed header and navbar, the footer appears below content now but not at the bottom of the screen (at 100%) It is 100% + the extra height of the header and navbar. Is there a way around this?